# How can I extract elements from a record using an integer reference in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, record

Firstly here is what I'm aiming to do, using made-up VHDL syntax...

```
type type_johns_record is
  first_element : std_logic;
  second_element: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  third_element : boolean;
end record;
....
....

for ii in johns_record'range loop
  if johns_record.type_johns_record'val(ii) = .... then
    exit;
  end if;
end loop;
```

Hopefully you can see that I'm trying to reference the elements of a record using similar syntax to that which can be used to reference an enumerated type.  This however (of course) does not work.  Is there a similar syntax that will work?  My solution at the moment is to use a record_info field and work using std_logic_vectors as shown below....

```
type type_johns_record is record
    first_element : std_logic;
    second_element : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    third_element : boolean;
    record_info : type_integer_array(2 downto 0);
  end record;

  function type_johns_record2slv(d : type_johns_record) return std_logic_vector is
  begin
    return (d.first_element & d.second_element & bool2sl(d.third_element));
  end function;

  constant johns_record_zero : type_johns_record := (first_element => '0',
                                                     second_element => "0000",
                                                     third_element => false,
                                                     record_info => (1, 4, 1));

  -- can be used with any type for which a record_info is known
  function get_record_element(input : std_logic_vector; element_number : integer; record_info :     type_integer_array) return std_logic_vector is
    variable r : type_slv32_array(record_info'length-1 downto 0);
    variable pos : integer := 0;
  begin
    for ii in record_info'range loop
      r(ii)(record_info(ii)-1 downto 0) := input(pos+record_info(ii)-1 downto pos);      
    end loop;
    return r(element_number)(record_info(element_number)-1 downto 0);
  end function;
```

I can then use these functions (which are in a package) as follows...

```
 for ii in johns_record.record_info'range loop
   if get_record_element(type_johns_record2slv(johns_record), ii, johns_record.record_info) = conv_std_logic_vector(4, johns_record.record_info(ii)) then
      exit;
   end if;
 end loop;
```

This really sucks and specifying the record_info is error prone and only marginally less time consuming that writing out individual element comparisons line by line.  Please offer a better solution!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the IEEE VHDL Standards group, there are actually two proposals relating to this:
http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/RecordMemberAttribute
 and 
http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/RecordIntrospection

This does not mean relax, someone else will address the issue.  Instead, we need you to comment on it and/or propose additional use models (to help with justification).  All of our work is done by volunteers - just like you - no memberships required for basic participation.  Much of our work is done on the TWIKI and email reflector and all with VHDL background are welcome to participate.  Drop me an email, I will get you setup - see my Stack Exchange profile for details.

To participate, start here:  http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/

Current proposals:
http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/CollectedRequirements

Meeting information:
http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/MeetingMinutes

Comment: Thanks for these resource links.  The hope that a good answer will 'soon' be possible

Comment: @JohnHarrison This is exactly the kind of use case I was hoping to enable with the [RecordIntrospection proposal](http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/RecordIntrospection).  Sadly in EDA terms *soon* means partial tool support around 2020!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to shorten your implementation code slightly, you could write a custom function for each record type (which you already have to do to convert to slv; this would just be a bit longer) that returns the nth element, like:

```
function get_record_element(input : johns_record_type; element_number : natural) return std_logic_vector is
begin
  case element_number is
    when 0 =>
      return to_slv(input.first_element);
    when 1 =>
      return to_slv(input.second_element);
    ...
end function;

...    

if get_record_element(johns_record, 2) = ... then
```

where `to_slv` is just a set of helper functions to convert other types. Is that more or less tedious than writing a more generic function and using an extra record element?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a record, then an array may be used, where the index value are based on an enumerated type, and the array elements are a super-set of the required type.  Declaration like:

```
type johns_elements_t is (FIRST, SECOND, THIRD);
subtype johns_type_t is std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- Super-set of required types
type johns_array_t is array (johns_elements_t) of johns_type_t;
signal johns_array : johns_array_t;
```

Use is then like:

```
for johns_index in johns_array'range loop
  if johns_array(johns_index) = "0000" then
    exit;
  end if;
```

VHDL attributes can be used to convert the values in the enumerated type between natural, like for example:

```
for natural_index in 0 to johns_elements_t'pos(johns_elements_t'high) loop
  if johns_array(johns_elements_t'val(natural_index)) = "0000" then
```

Access to elements must then take into account how the contents is used for each elements accessed by the values in the enumerated type, but that is the case anyway when using a record, but now where is no type checking in the compiler.  Another use case is:

```
if johns_array(FIRST)(0) = '1' then  -- Used as std_logic
  johns_array(FIRST)(0) <= '0';
  ...
```

In synthesis, the tool is likely to remove the unused bits in elements where only a subset of the bits are used, so the final design is not larger.

Also, some synthesis tools (for example Altera Quartus II) does not accept functions that return variable length results like `std_logic_vector`, so a solution for synthesis should taken that into account, since a functions like `get_record_element` may result in an error.

Comment: OK, however, VHDL arrays require that the elements are not only of the same type, but also have the same dimensions.  So this solution is much more limiting than @fru1bat

Comment: But the limitations may be required for synthesis, since I expect that most synthesis tools will throw an error (like Quartus II does) for functions like `get_record_element` that returns variable length `std_logic_vector`.

Comment: first I concede.  When I look the OP's record, returning std_logic_vector will not be so convenient for the 4th element which is an integer_vector, so while both may work for many practical examples, neither are going to work as the problem gets more general.

Comment: second, WRT the Quartus error, was it the function or the usage of the function that was an issue?  I have a Mux4 function that returns an object that is based on the selected input.  So if the inputs were different size, it can return different size values, however, when you do the assignment, it is likely to generate an error - unless the output of the Mux4 is passed to something that resizes it (ie: resize, "+", "-").  I decided that my original implementation of Mux4 was bad and instead rewrote it to follow the sizing rules of logic operators (input arrays must match in size).

Comment: It is the usage of the function that causes the Quartus error, so it would be OK to have a Mux4 function that takes generic `std_logic_vector` arguments, but at each call all `return` in the function must have same length, even if resizing is done immediately on the return value.

Comment: Thanks for the effort in this answer.  I considered a similar implementation but wanted the convenience of assigning individual different typed record element (which I do hundreds of times) more than the need for the element addressing (which I need to do once) which was the subject of the question.